# Angular 5: Two routes (parameterised vs non-parameterised) navigate to the same component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have some routes like this:

```
  { path: 'bill', component: BillListComponent },
  { path: 'bill/:id', component: BillDetailComponent },
  { path: 'bill/save', component: BillSaveComponent },
  { path: 'bill/save/:id', component: BillSaveComponent },
```

and in my component has buttons response to click events in methods like the following but they navigate to the same location:

```
  redirectToBillDetail(item: Bill) {
      this.router.navigate(['bill', item.id]);
  }
  redirectToBillNew() {
      this.router.navigate(['bill/save']);
  }
```

They both navigate to the BillDetailComponent (the links on browser address bar is correct bill/save vs bill/ID_1234). Could anyone show me what I'm wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to move the `bill/:id` route to the bottom of the array, otherwise the router has no idea whether `save` is supposed to be an `id`. As soon as it matches a route it will take that route

Comment: Thanks you, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Angular doesn't know whether `save` is a value for the `:id` parameter. In fact, as soon as it finds a matching route, it will take that route.

To get around this, you should put the more specific route first, so:

```
{ path: 'bill', component: BillListComponent },
{ path: 'bill/save', component: BillSaveComponent },
{ path: 'bill/:id', component: BillDetailComponent },
{ path: 'bill/save/:id', component: BillSaveComponent },
```

This way, it will only try the `:id` route after trying to match the `save` route

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the param in the ngOnInit within your invoking component and then invoke the required function router can't judge between save and save:id

```
ngOnInit(){

if (this.route.snapshot.params['id']) {
        redirectToBillDetail(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
    }
    else
     {
        redirectToNewBill();
      }
    }
```